# cannot writing list to csv in python

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a list of unicode string that I want to write to a cvs file.

```
with open(archive_dir_today + 'myfile.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(list_diff_1)
```

this work fine, except that it writes every character in a separate cell.
For example the first entry in the list is `"1000F034E2"`
I end up with a row in the csv file that looks like this:

```
1,0,0,0,F,0,3,4,E,2
```

what is causing that problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong method; `writer.writerows()` expects **multiple rows**, but you only have *one* row. Use `writer.writerow()` (singular, no `s`) instead.

What happens is that because `writerows()` expects a list of rows, it treats each column in your single row as a list; the list of a unicode string is its individual characters:

```
>>> list(u'1000F034E2')
[u'1', u'0', u'0', u'0', u'F', u'0', u'3', u'4', u'E', u'2']
```

That's the row of columns being written out in that case.

If you wanted each item in the list as separate rows, then *wrap them in list objects*:

```
writer.writerows([column] for column in list_diff_1)
```

Comment: I want each item in the list on a separate row. Not all in one row.